# Return name of property based on Value in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, properties

**I want to retrieve the name of property based on its value. value is string type & property name is Field type in dictionary definition. My Method is like this-**

I have tried below option but not getting desired reult. Anybody can help

```
public void RetriveDiagCodeName(
            [FieldName("DIAG_CODE1")] Field<string> diagCode1,
            [FieldName("DIAG_CODE2")] Field<string> diagCode2)
    {

            Dictionary<string, Field<string>> dictDiagCode = new Dictionary<string,Field<string>>();
            dictDiagCode.Add("1", diagCode1);
            dictDiagCode.Add("2", diagCode2);

        Field<string> diagCodeName;
        string diagCodeValue = "1234B;

        diagCodename = dictDiagCode.Keys.OfType<Field<string>>().FirstOrDefault(k=> dictDiagCode[k] == diagCodeValue);
    }
```

Comment: So what you expect to get in `diagCodename`?

Comment: I am expecting diagCode1 or diagCode2. As input parameter to my method "RetriveDiagCodeName" will have some value as well. but I do not want those values. I want value container name as Field<string> type.

Comment: `dictDiagCode.Keys.OfType<Field<string>>()` is obvious non-sense as the keys are of striong.type, not of `Field<string>`-type.

Comment: @AsitSingh you can achieve that by using reflection.

Comment: How do you compare a `Field<string>` with a `string`? Your value within the dictionary is of `Field<string>`-type, however you´re searching for the string `"1234B"`.

Comment: That my concern now. I have string value and based on that value I need Field<string> field

Comment: Where does `Field` come from?